# Using multiple of the same methods and time complexity

Tags: java, linked-list, time-complexity

For the code block below, I was wondering if the total time complexity for it would be O(n^2) or something greater. I know that the get() method for a linked list runs O(n) time but does it matter that I have used it multiple times?  Since I've used it 3 times would get() be O(n^3) or stay at O(n)?

```
public static LinkedList<Integer> merge(LinkedList<Integer> a, LinkedList<Integer> b){
        LinkedList<Integer> c = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
            if (i >= a.size()) { // 4
                c.add(b.get(i)); // 4
            }
            else {
                b.add(i, a.get(i));
                c.add(b.get(i));
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Hey! The loop has linear complexity, so it is *O(n)*. The code in the `if` has complexity *O(n)* and the code in the `else` has *O(n)* as well. This is because `get` has a linear complexity for `LinkedList`. It doesn't matter for *O* if the `else` has `get` two times, this is just a constant factor, which is dropped in *O*. So the overall complexity is *O(n)* times *O(n)* that is *O(n^2)*.

Answer (score 0):

Access in a linked list implementation is O(n). To `add` an element from the list, there is a loop that follows links from one element to the next. In the worst case, in a list of `n` elements, `n` iterations of the loop are executed.